# Apache2: RADIUS authentication before rewrite engine HTTPS

Tags: apache-2.4, ssl-certificate, https, mod-rewrite, radius

I tried to set up a reverse proxy with HTTPS and Radius authentication. Unfortunately, I don't get an authentication query before it redirects to the HTTPS page. What did I do wrong?

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  <Proxy *>
     Require all granted
  </Proxy>

  ServerName xxx.xxx.de
  DocumentRoot /var/www/html

  ProxyPreserveHost On

        <Location />
                Options Indexes FollowSymlinks
                AuthType Basic
                AuthName "Apache Radius authentication"
                AuthBasicAuthoritative Off
                AuthBasicProvider radius
                AuthRadiusAuthoritative on
                AuthRadiusActive On
                Require valid-user
       </Location>
  AddRadiusAuth Server_IP:1812 Token 5
  ProxyPass /.well-known !
  ProxyPass / http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:80/
  ProxyPassReverse / http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:80/

  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =xxx.xxx.de
  RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]

</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Why would you like to authenticate in plain text? Doesn't sound right...

Comment: I only need a RADIUS authentication before forwarding to the HTTPS side. I don't know how else I could do that ... I've been looking in the forum all day.

Comment: The "problem" may be to do with the order in which the config sections are merged. `<Location>` sections are merged very late. Can you contain your authentication directives in a `<Directory>` container instead? http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/sections.html#merging